# How can I know when video play?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have video in my project. I play it with MPMoviePlayerController but app will take time to load for a sec. Now I want to lunch another func. when video start to play. How can I know when video already load and start play and How to call another func. when it play ???

Could U guide me please ?

here is some simple code

```
-(IBAction)testVideoLongPress:(id)sender
{
    NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video1" ofType:@"MOV"];
    movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];
    movie.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    movie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    movie.shouldAutoplay = YES;

    movie.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 720, 1280);
    [self.view addSubview:movie.view];
    [movie play];
}

-(void)wannalunchthismethod
{
....
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [`MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification) notification of `MPMoviePlayerController` and you'll be able to catch your movie player state changing to "play".

Comment: I got it but I ask for a question.
if ([movie loadState] == MPMovieLoadStatePlayable) {
        NSLog(@"MPMovieLoadStatePlayable");
    }
    else if ([movie loadState] == MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK) 
    {
        NSLog(@"MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK");
    }
    else if ([movie loadState] == MPMovieLoadStateStalled)
    {
        NSLog(@"MPMovieLoadStateStalled");
    }
    else if ([movie loadState] == MPMovieLoadStateUnknown) 
    {
        NSLog(@"MPMovieLoadStateUnknown");
    }  
when will all those NSLog will show. I dont understand stateplayable , Playthroughok and stalled.

Comment: @crazyoxygen if you take a look at [Apple's documentation for MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and search for `MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK`, you might see what these different states mean.